# How to fit image in React Native UI Kitten Card Header

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to add an image inside React Native UI Kitten Card Header. However, it doesn't fit in the card header. Please see the attached image

[image]

How can I totally fit the image inside Card Header? Current Code is,

```
  const renderItemHeader = (headerProps) => (
  <Image
      style={styles.articleImage}
      source={{
          uri: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg'
        }}
        resizeMode={'cover'} 
    />);
```

And The style

```
articleImage: {
  flex: 1,
  height: 150,
  width: '100%',
  resizeMode: 'cover',
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting following styles on image, fixed the issue

```
marginVertical: -16,
marginBottom:0
```

Full Styles,

```
articleImage: {
  flex: 1,
  height: 170,
  width: '100%',
  marginVertical: -16,
  marginBottom:0
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. create a custom mapping.json file

```
export const mapping = {
  components: {
    Card: {
      appearances: {
        outline: {
          mapping: {
            bodyPaddingHorizontal: 16,
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
```

2. find your application provider and add a customMapping

```
import React from 'react';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { default as mapping } from './path-to/mapping.json'; // <-- import mapping

export default () => (
  <ApplicationProvider 
    {...eva}
    customMapping={mapping} // <-- apply mapping
    theme={eva.light}>
  </ApplicationProvider>
);
```

Links:
[ui kitten docs on custom mappings](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/design-system/customize-mapping#merge-mappings) and [similar github issue](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/issues/1002)

Comment: I think this may work for card body. Not for card header?

Answer (score 0):

**mapping.json**

```
{
  "components": {
    "Card": {
      "meta": {
        "scope": "all",
        "parameters": {},
        "variantGroups": {},
        "states": {},
        "appearances": {
          "outline": {
            "default": true
          }
        }
      },
      "appearances": {
        "outline": {
          "mapping": {
            "headerPaddingHorizontal": 0, // !!! for Card Header you need "headerPadding..."
            "headerPaddingVertical": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**file with ApplicationProvider**

```js
import React from 'react';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { default as mapping } from './path-to/mapping.json';

export default () => (
  <ApplicationProvider 
    {...eva}
    customMapping={mapping}
    theme={eva.light}
>
  ...Your content...
  </ApplicationProvider>
);
```